# how to use a proxy with wolfSSL

Tags: wolfssl

Do I handle the proxy connection myself using wolfSSL or are there function(s) that do the CONNECT request for you? If not, should I first, connect to the proxy then second, make the CONNECT request then third, connect using SSL?

Comment: One would typically connect to the proxy server first then once the proxy is established issue a TLS connection request for a website or domain on the other side of the proxy. Proxies can use their own SSL/TLS for a secure proxy connection or they might not have any encryption at all. A seperate TLS connection can be issued through the proxy connection regardless. wolfSSL has done some testing running through udp-proxy but not securing the proxy itself, see https://github.com/wolfSSL/udp-proxy for an example and instructions on setting up a local test. Can you explain more about your use case?

Answer (score 1):

As a tentative answer to the question without knowing more about which proxy is being used or the use-case...

Do the latter IE establish the proxy connection using the proxy API then issue the TLS connection to a server running on the other side of the proxy. An example of this is detailed in the README here: https://github.com/wolfSSL/udp-proxy

Now if there is a desire to use wolfSSL to secure the proxy connection as opposed to issuing the TLS connection THROUGH the proxy connection that is a different use-case. You can send more info to support@wolfssl.com if you need direct pre-sales support, the wolfSSL team is responsive and helpful.

- K